# when toggle a div, how to let the user on top on that div instead of being scroll in the middle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

here is my problem,

On click of a button, I have a div being toggle underneath ( quite long). it ( randomly) bring the user on the middle of the new div, I would like to let the user on the top  of this new div instead.

How is this possible to achieve ?

Here is my current jquery:

```
$(document).on("click",".more, .more-com, .more-com-film",function() {
    $(".all-content-news, .all-content-news-single").css("display","none");
    // $(".overlaybg").css("display","none");

            //         $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().children('.action-container-com-film').css("top","9.9%");

            $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().children('.overlaybg').css("display","none");
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().children('.all-content-news-single').fadeToggle();
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().children('.entry-title-wrapper').css("background","rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)");
```

click on .more-com, toggle the new div .all-content-news-single

Any highlight will be wonderful, thank you so much !!

Comment: Please provide your HTML/css code as well

Comment: or create a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I m working with squarespace, it is going to be tuff but i ll try, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you need append particular element before or after

You can put on following code:

```
 $(".all-content-news-single").append("<span>Hello world!</span>");

 $("<span>Hello world!</span>").insertAfter(".all-content-news-single");

 $( "<span>Hello world!</span>" ).insertBefore( ".all-content-news-single" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind a event for know the start or the end of your toogle:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click",".more, .more-com, .more-com-film",function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().children('.all-content-news-single').fadeToggle({
            start:function() {
                console.log('start');
            },
            done:function(data) {
                console.log('done');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Then use a classic ancor or a script to scroll to your target
https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo